# How to pass value from one atomic block to another atomic block

Tags: haskell, ghc

In the following code (Pl. see myTransaction) I want to atomically read from a TVar n1  and update another TVar n2, on the basis that read value after certain delay. Problem is that I couldn't pass the read value form one atomic block to another atomic block.

```
module SimpleSTM
where
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Concurrent
import System.IO.Unsafe
import System.Random 

type GNum = TVar Int
updateNum :: GNum -> Int -> STM ()
updateNum n v =  writeTVar n v 

myTransaction :: GNum -> GNum -> Int -> IO ()
myTransaction n1 n2 v = do
    atomically $ do 
        x <- readTVar n1
        let y =  (x + v )      -- Getting Error: Not an expression

    randomDelay

    atomically $ updateNum n2 y  -- Getting Error: Not in scope: 'y' 


randomDelay = do delay <- getStdRandom(randomR (1,3)) 
     threadDelay (delay * 1000000) 

main :: IO ()
main = do n1 <- newTVarIO 1
  n2 <- newTVarIO 1


  n1v <- readTVarIO n1
  n2v <- readTVarIO n2

  putStrLn ("n1 = " ++ (show n1v) ++ " n2= " ++ (show n2v))


  forkIO (myTransaction n1 n2 1)
  forkIO (myTransaction n2 n1 2)
  forkIO (myTransaction n2 n1 3)    

  n1v <- readTVarIO n1
  n2v <- readTVarIO n2

  putStrLn ("n1 = " ++ (show n1v) ++ " n2= " ++ (show n2v))
```

The code is generating following error:

```
The last statement in a 'do' loop must be an expression
   let y = (x + v)
SimpleSTM1.hs:24:43: Not in scope: 'y'
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run

```
myTransaction :: GNum -> GNum -> Int -> IO ()
myTransaction n1 n2 v = do
    y <- atomically $ do 
        x <- readTVar n1
        return (x + v)
    randomDelay
    atomically $ updateNum n2 y
```

but be warned that this runs *two* atomic transactions. I.e., there might be updates between the read and the successive write, causing the whole `myTransaction` to be non-atomic.

---

If you really want an atomic delayed transaction, you could run something like

```
myTransaction :: GNum -> GNum -> Int -> IO ()
myTransaction n1 n2 v =
    atomically $ do 
        x <- readTVar n1
        unsafePerformIO randomDelay `seq` return ()
        updateNum n2 (x + v)
```

where the `unsafePerformIO` simulates a pure computation taking some time to terminate. Please note that `unsafePerformIO` is generally a very bad idea to do anything, since it's really unsafe. However, if you use it to simulate something that could be done by pure code, it is OK to use it.

Alternatively, [`unsafeIOtoSTM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/GHC-Conc-Sync.html#v:unsafeIOToSTM) also works, and carries similar warnings as `unsafePerformIO`.

Note however that in "production" code there's no reason why you would add a delay inside a transaction. I am therefore guessing you want to do this only for the sake of experimenting with STM, perhaps to empirically check its atomicity guarantees.

Comment: Thank you Chi. As you said, it's become not-atomic thus cannot solve my purpose.

Comment: @AmmlanGhosh It's however not clear why do you want a delay within the STM monad. Is it just for experimenting with it, and not for any "real" purpose? Then, you could use "unsafe" stuff to do it anyway.

Comment: Dear Chi, I have added my new code posted as Answer. I want to check how transaction re-executes. Please the check the code.